# How to capture keyboard input without a text box in Eto

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, gtk, eto

I have a project ([Void](https://github.com/PolyglotSymposium/void)) using the [Eto](https://github.com/picoe/Eto) GUI framework for .NET and Mono. I am building a Vim-like text editor which will have at least some of the modes which Vim has (and yes, I know, [one does not simply...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbOnh.jpg)).

The basic structure of my GUI is just a [`Form`](https://github.com/PolyglotSymposium/void/blob/master/Void/Void/MainForm.cs) whose `Content` is a `Drawable`, so that I have maximum flexibility over something which does not adhere to the normal styles of GUI apps. I have successfully attached a `KeyUp` handler to the form when I stubbed out Normal mode and I have the `ZQ` command closing the window.

```
KeyUp += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    var keyPress = eventArgs.AsVoidKeyPress();
    if (keyPress != null)
    {
        handler(keyPress);
    }
};
```

That's fine and dandy for Normal mode, but for other modes such as Command Mode and Insert Mode, I want to be able to catch special key combinations (i.e. ones that use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>) but other than that I just want to capture stuff as text. This will allow me to handle Unicode, etc. In other words, I don't simply want to translate keystrokes back into text myself.

I tried to attach a `TextInput` event.

```
Console.WriteLine("I see this, but...");
TextInput += (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("...I don't see this, no matter what I type.");
};
```

I even commented out my subscription to the `KeyUp` event to see if that is conflicting, but I just don't get any response. Is this because I am attaching it directly to the form? Is there any way to capture text input without actually using a text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextInput` event has been fully implemented in the develop branch (upcoming 2.1 release), which you can use via the [myget](https://www.myget.org/F/eto/) feed.  This should capture text input from `Drawable` and other controls like `TextBox`, etc.  It was used to implement the new `MaskedTextBox`, which is just a subclass of `TextBox`.

It shouldn't conflict with the KeyDown/KeyUp events, unless you set the event argument's `Handled` property to `true`

Comment: Excellent--I'm glad to see this.